# WordPress cache feeds

Tags: rss, cache

I would like to implement a custom cache for all the feeds in my site. The rss requests are very intensive and I have a big db load.

Do anyone know of a good action before running the rss query so I can cache it? I'm using memcahed and all the feeds should be cached for 1 hour.

Comment: If WordPress doesn't already do this, I think it's a huge problem. When I rewrote WordPress from scratch for a client, I realized his RSS feeds were getting hammered and I created a cache system so that nobody ever waits for a RSS feed, it always shows a cached version first, then refresh after the user was served. Anyway, I am running into this problem again because of a DOS attack on /feed/. I do not want an "all-inclusive" plugin that wants to make me breakfast in bed, I only want to cache the RSS feed.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress already caches feeds to an extent, but for better caching install one of the caching plugins. E.g. W3 Total Cache has the option to cache RSS Feeds.